# Generating pdf in php using mpdf not working

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf

I installed mpdf successfully via composer.

Here is my PHP code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1>test</h1>");
$file='abcd.pdf';
$mpdf->output($file,'I');
```

PDF won't generate. I tried in Chrome and Firefox.
The location of autoload.php is correct.
I tried D, F and S as well, as the second argument for `$mpdf->output`, none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code actually works, please double check your `php version`
and note that mpdf is compatible only with `PHP ≥ 5.6.0 and < 7.4.0.`

https://mpdf.github.io/about-mpdf/requirements-v7.html

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1>test</h1>");
$file='abcd.pdf';

$mpdf->OutputHttpDownload($file);
```

You can use the OutputHttpDownload method passing the name of your file and it will work!